# Link table to another table

Tags: datamodel, bi-publisher, oraclereports, oracle-sql-data-modeler

I'm creating new data model in oracle fusion cloud. I have a different tables, and I want to link all 3 of them. What should I do?
Below are the tables i used:

```
doo_headers_all dha,
ra_terms rt,
ra_customer_trx_all rcta,
hz_cust_site_uses_all bill_hcsua,
hz_cust_acct_sites_all bill_hcasa,
hz_cust_accounts bill_hca,
hz_party_sites bill_hps,
hz_parties bill_hp,
hz_party_site_uses ship_hpsu,
hz_party_sites ship_hps,
hz_parties ship_hp,
hz_addtnl_party_names bill_hapn,
hz_addtnl_party_names ship_hapn
```

I link all of them except for DOO_HEADERS_ALL, I tried to search which foreign keys can I use so that I can link it all but I don't see any answer.

```
rcta.term_id = rt.term_id(+)
and rcta.bill_to_site_use_id = bill_hcsua.site_use_id(+)
and bill_hcsua.cust_acct_site_id  = bill_hcasa.cust_acct_site_id(+)
and bill_hcasa.cust_account_id = bill_hca.cust_account_id(+)
and bill_hcasa.party_site_id = bill_hps.party_site_id(+)
and bill_hps.party_id = bill_hp.party_id(+)
and rcta.ship_to_party_site_use_id = ship_hpsu.party_site_use_id(+)
and ship_hpsu.party_site_id = ship_hps.party_site_id(+)   
and ship_hps.party_id = ship_hp.party_id(+)
and bill_hp.party_id = bill_hapn.party_id(+) and bill_hapn.party_name_type (+) = 'PHONETIC'
and ship_hp.party_id = ship_hapn.party_id(+) and ship_hapn.party_name_type (+) = 'PHONETIC'
```

this is I used to link other tables except doo_headers_all

Answer (score 0):

```
dha.ORDER_NUMBER = rcta.CT_REFERENCE(+)
```

or

```
dha.SOLD_TO_CUSTOMER_ID = bill_hca.CUST_ACCOUNT_ID (+)
```

This is highly dependent on your setup though.
It's also not really clear what you mean by 'different tables, and I want to link all 3 of them', as your list is a lot longer than 3 tables.